# Python 3.11 broke Ansible WINRM connection

Tags: python, ansible, kerberos, winrm

I wanted to use Microsoft AD Plugin in Ansible, so based on the pre-requisites, I tried to upgrade Python from 3.6.8 to greater version, exactly Python 3.11.6 and  installed the main pre-requisites such as below

- dnspython - For option server lookup support
- pyspnego >= 0.8.0
- pyspnego[kerberos] - This package did not installed

I believe that the above packages broke down the WINRM connection. I had to remove the python 3.11.6 version by removing the installed files in this directories

- usr/local/lib/python3.11
- /usr/local/include/python3.11

Still winrm did not worked, so I had to remove the previously installed pre-requisites package such as

- dnspython - For option server lookup support
- pyspnego >= 0.8.0

Still, when I tried to test winrm connection, it throw as below

```
calling kinit with subprocess for principal serviceaccount@domain.com
kinit succeeded for principal serviceaccount@domain.com
<TargetHost001.domain.com> WINRM CONNECT: transport=kerberos endpoint=http://TargetHost001.domain.com:5985/wsman
<TargetHost001.domain.com> WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 248, in send_message
    root = ET.fromstring(ex.response_text)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1314, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 118, column 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py", line 426, in _winrm_connect
    self.shell_id = protocol.open_shell(codepage=65001)  # UTF-8
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 251, in send_message
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
    resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 309, in send_message
    self.build_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 292, in build_session
    self.setup_encryption()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 298, in setup_encryption
    self._send_message_request(prepared_request, '')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 338, in _send_message_request
    raise WinRMTransportError('http', ex.response.status_code, response_text)
winrm.exceptions.WinRMTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403
TargetHost001.domain.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "kerberos: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403",
    "unreachable": true
```

}

Ansible.cfg file has the below

```
[defaults]
force_color = true
nocows = 0
inventory = hosts
roles_path = /etc/ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles
action_warnings = true
collections_paths = ~/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules
collections_scan_sys_path = True
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3
deprecation_warnings=False
callbacks_enabled= ansible.posix.profile_tasks,ansible.posix.timer,ansible.posix.profile_roles
```

I tried deleting Python 3.11 and uninstalled pyspnego and dnspython modules through pip but still I could not connect with WINRM from Ansible

Comment: Did you check the logs on windows side to understand why you get an http/403? This looks more like an authentication issue than a problem with your python version.

Comment: @Zeitounator, When I execute the below command 
```winrs -r:http://server:5985/wsman -u:Username -p:Password ipconfig, ```
targeting the specific remote host from my local laptop, I am able to the IP address details. So there is no issue with WinRM or anything related to Remote powershell.
Thus, I can deduce that this issue is with Ansible WINRM and its related python packages

Comment: So there's an issue with your credentials in your inventory then probably...

Comment: @Zeitounator, IN my original post, I used a service account and the same service account is able to execute KINIT successfully. (Please refer second line inside the output in my original post). By which means, the credentials are working fine. I also tested with the same credentials by manually executing Kinit and I am able to get a TGT ticket.

Answer (score -1):

I found that this issue has nothing to do with Python package or its version but somehow installing and manually deleting the directories for Python3.11 screwed the bashrc profile where I had mentioned the proxy details as below

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,127.0.1.1
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,127.0.1.1
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://xxx.domain.com:8080
export https_proxy=http://xxx.domain.com:8080
export http_proxy=http://xxx.domain.com:8080
export HTTP_PROXY=http://xxx.domain.com:8080
```

I had to comment and modify the profile as below

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,127.0.1.1
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,127.0.1.1
export https_proxy=http://xxx.domain.com:8080
```

The above modification made Ansible and WinRM again started to work.